# How to find graph with maximum energy on 10 vertices?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

Give a graph G which has maximum energy among all graphs with 10 vertices.

My approach: For any graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, $\varepsilon(G) \leq n(1 + \sqrt{n})/2$.

For a given $n$, this upper bound is attained if there is a strongly regular
graph with parameters $(n, k, a, c)$ satisfying $k = (n + \sqrt{n})/2$, and $a = c = (n + 2\sqrt{n})/4$

But here $n$ must be even perfect square. But for my case $n = 10$. How to proceed?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Could you give us some background on your problem ? Where does it come from? what do you know? what have you tried ?

Comment: After some research, the bound you are given is attained **if and only if** there is such a strongly regular graph. Therefore the bound will not be attained. Do you have any other result you could use?